# how to pass var from apex:repeat tag to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat

How can I pass the `var` attribute from my `<apex:repeat>` tag to a controller variable? Here `var` contains API name of object field. From that I need to get label for that particular field to display it in table column. I am using facet to display column label.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!SelectedFields}" var="FieldLable"  id="xyz">  
    <apex:column id="clm" >                   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!ab.con[FieldLable]}" />
        <apex:facet name="header">{!Lable}</apex:facet>                       
    </apex:column>                      
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass it to `Apex`. Just use the `$ObjectType` global variable. Here I will rename your variables to be less confusing and conform to your description. Please also note it's `label`, not `lable`.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedFields}" var="fieldName">
    <apex:facet name="header">
        {!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.fields[fieldName].label}
    </apex:facet>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: thanks adrain . It helped ,
this is what i used
  <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType[selectedObject].fields[FieldLable].Label}</apex:facet>

Comment: @mak If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.